# Dagger bad implementation ? with kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2

I have problems with the component

```
@PerActivity
@Component(dependencies = arrayOf(ApplicationComponent::class), modules = arrayOf(ActivityModule::class, LoginModule::class))
interface LoginComponent {

    fun inject(poLoginActivity: LoginActivity)
}
```

I have error in this interface component:

Gradle Console Error:

```
e: /Users/everis/MARLON/PROYECTO/LIAISON/ANDROID/liaison-kt/app/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/projectDebug/com/stb/stbandroid/internal/di/component/LoginComponent.java:4: error: com.stb.stbandroid.internal.di.component.LoginComponent scoped with @com.stb.stbandroid.internal.di.PerActivity may not reference bindings with different scopes:
e: 

e: @dagger.Component(dependencies = {com.stb.stbandroid.internal.di.component.ApplicationComponent.class}, modules = {com.stb.stbandroid.internal.di.module.ActivityModule.class, com.stb.stbandroid.internal.di.module.LoginModule.class})
e: ^
e:       @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull @Singleton @Provides error.NonExistentClass com.stb.stbandroid.internal.di.module.LoginModule.loginRepository$app_projectDebug(error.NonExistentClass)
e:       @Singleton class com.stb.stbandroid.model.mapper.UserModelMapper
e: /Users/everis/MARLON/PROYECTO/LIAISON/ANDROID/liaison-kt/app/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/projectDebug/com/stb/stbandroid/internal/di/component/LoginComponent.java:8: error: error.NonExistentClass is bound multiple times:
e: 

e:     public abstract void inject(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
e:                          ^
e:       @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull error.NonExistentClass com.stb.stbandroid.internal.di.component.MainComponent.threadExecutor()
e:       @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull error.NonExistentClass com.stb.stbandroid.internal.di.component.MainComponent.postExecutionThread()
e:       @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull error.NonExistentClass com.stb.stbandroid.internal.di.component.ApplicationComponent.loginRepository()
e:       @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull @Singleton @Provides error.NonExistentClass com.stb.stbandroid.internal.di.module.LoginModule.loginRepository$app_projectDebug(error.NonExistentClass)
e: /Users/everis/MARLON/PROYECTO/LIAISON/ANDROID/liaison-kt/app/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/projectDebug/com/stb/stbandroid/internal/di/component/ApplicationComponent.java:6: error: [com.stb.stbandroid.internal.di.component.MainComponent.threadExecutor()] error.NonExistentClass is bound multiple times:
e: 

e: public abstract interface ApplicationComponent extends com.stb.stbandroid.internal.di.component.MainComponent {
e:                 ^
e:       @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull @Singleton @Provides error.NonExistentClass com.stb.stbandroid.internal.di.module.ApplicationModule.provideThreadExecutor(error.NonExistentClass)
e:       @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull @Singleton @Provides error.NonExistentClass com.stb.stbandroid.internal.di.module.ApplicationModule.providePostExecutionThread(com.stb.stbandroid.UIThread)
e:       @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull @Singleton @Provides error.NonExistentClass com.stb.stbandroid.internal.di.module.ApplicationModule.loginRepository(error.NonExistentClass)
e: /Users/everis/MARLON/PROYECTO/LIAISON/ANDROID/liaison-kt/app/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/projectDebug/com/stb/stbandroid/internal/di/component/ApplicationComponent.java:9: error: error.NonExistentClass is bound multiple times:
e: 

e:     public abstract error.NonExistentClass loginRepository();
```

Answer (score 1):

> LoginComponent scoped with @com.stb.stbandroid.internal.di.PerActivity may not reference bindings with different scopes

Seems like you're trying to provide `@Singleton` from your `@PerActivity LoginComponent`. Those are 2 different scopes, and one component can only provide one scope at a time.

- If the object is actually intended to be `@Singleton` scoped, then move it to your `AppComponent` (any module will do) and it will be properly handled like the rest of your `@Singleton`s.
- If it should be created *once per Activity* then you should use `@PerActivity` instead of `@Singleton` on your `@Provides` method and it will be properly created and managed by your `LoginComponent`.

You can't mix and match. Any module you add to your `LoginComponent` has to use the `@PerActivity` scope (or no scope at all) for its `@Provides` method.

Comment: But that work fine in java, but now change to kotlin find this problem